# When was "Guru" - sanskrit term meaning teacher - popularized?

Tags: historical-change, popularity

I was interested to know about term [Guru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guru), when it was popularized really in Western countries ? At first I was trying to do a [google books search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Guru&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=7&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CGuru%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BGuru%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bguru%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGURU%3B%2Cc0) of a word which showed that popularity of phrase sharply increased in 1955. So first question would be what affected such increase in popularity of "Guru" in google books at that time ? My first guess is that because of movie "[MR. & MRS. ’55 (1955)](https://moviepedia.in/bollywood-movies/mr-mrs-55-1955-gurudutt/)" where director and one of cast crew is *Guru Dutt*. If it is so then event is not related to "Guru" term as a teacher at all. And second question would be - When really Guru synonym of teacher was really popularized in **Western** culture / countries ? Was "Guru" term popularized because of guru movement and interaction with hippies at 1960s-1970s at Western Europe and USA ? Or some other event induced peak in term's popularity ?

Comment: Blame the British in India. Most Hindu loanwords come from that era.

Comment: Gurus in pajamas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

guru a noun [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=guru) 1940:

> Generalized sense of "mentor" is from 1940 (in H.G. Wells); sense of
>   "expert in something" first recorded c. 1966 in Canadian English in
>   reference to Marshall McLuhan.

From this citation, guru pre-dates the hippies. Your reference to the movie seems unlikely as just an actor named Guru (1st name) was in it.

The [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/82664?redirectedFrom=guru#eid) says the following and dates early usage to ~ 1600:

- > A Hindu spiritual **teacher** or head of a religious sect. Also in gen.
  >   or trivial use: an influential teacher; a mentor; a pundit.

> 1613   S. Purchas Pilgrimage 500   They have others which they call
>   **Gurupi**, learned Priests.

Other synonyms and their dates:

- catechizer   (c1449)
- mystagogue   (c1540)
- oracle (1548)
- catechist   (1564)
- guru   (1613)
- director   (1671)
- swami   (1901)

Comment: So seems that [H.G. Wells](https://books.google.lt/books?id=c4UoX6-Sv1AC&pg=PA600&lpg=PA600&dq=1940+H.G.+Wells+guru&source=bl&ots=V3Cn5qyuIm&sig=ACfU3U07tMYC-b_SlXgTnqNmyTWfEcxx_Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjW_a79xvTkAhVnyqYKHSq5BaAQ6AEwHnoECBAQAQ#v=onepage&q=1940%20H.G.%20Wells%20guru&f=false) has started everything in 1940 and hippies finished in 1970. Thanks for a very clear answer.